# Calculate Distance between Fourier Transforms

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I'm working with signal data (specifically data from accelerators and gyroscopes), and I take their Fourier transforms to get a better idea of the dominant frequencies.

I'd like to compare the Fourier transforms of two functions, but I haven't found an established method. I imagine that there is something more domain-specific (i.e. to the Fourier) than Euclidean distance but I'm not sure.

Comment: There are lots of ways of comparing, it really depends on what you want to do. The energy of the signal  $\int |x|^2$ is the same as $\int |\hat{x}|^2$ (modulo some $2 \pi$ constant, depending on the variety of transform.). However, using $|\hat{x}|^2$ lets you see how much energy of the difference is concentrated in  a particular bandwidth.

Comment: Could you explain some different ways of comparison and why you would use/avoid them? I'm very new to this particular field

Comment: Like I say, it depends on what you are trying to do. There are lots of norms, weighted or otherwise, but you need to give some idea of what you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: Well the data is generated from the accelerometers and gyroscopes of people walking, I want to see if there is a significant difference between the Fourier Transforms of different individuals, sexes, ages, etc. So I guess with that in mind I want to see how close the dominant frequencies are between the two samples? I apologize for my naivety; this isn't my domain at all.

Comment: No apologies necessary. I don't have good suggestions, I suspect you would need to look at a lot of plots to see what the overall characteristics are (fundamental frequences, etc.) to see what a meaningful measure might be. My suggestion of the $L^2$ norm is more likely to correlate to weight :-). You are probably better off experminenting rather than looking for some ideal way?

Comment: That's the problem. I don't know any ways (well other than the $L^2$ norm you just mentioned now) to experiment with.

Comment: Well, one thing to be careful with here (MSE) is that the word distance means something specific to mathematicians, whereas I think you are looking for distinguishing characteristics. Look for patterns in the dominant frequencies (are they roughly related in some way, look at the 'harmonic distortion', etc.).

Comment: I don't know if this is the right thing to do, but you could just correlate the spectrums. If they are shaped similarly (and I don't know that they are), then the peak of the cross-correlation should tell you how much one is shifted from the other. However, if you know their exists a dominant peak in each individual spectrum and you just want to know the distance between the peaks from different sample vectors, I'd suggest estimating the dominant frequency location for each vector of samples individually. Once you have the peak frequency, everything else should be straightforward.